# Show Content in a View if content Author has the same entity reference value as the logged in user

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Title pretty much explains it. I have a user entity reference field (Node) called "Company". I want to show all content in a view where the author of that content has the same "company" value as the logged in user. I'm getting a little confused with the relationships to achieve this.

Ok, I was able to get this working based on Kien's answer. If using Entity Reference 7-x.1.5 Instead of 'field_company_nid', the correct column name was 'field_company_target_id'

`/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function your_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'article' && $view->current_display == 'page') { // replace 'article' and 'page' by your view's machine name and display's machine name
    $author_join = new views_join();
    $author_join->table = 'field_data_field_company'; // 'field_company' is machine name of the user's field referencing to Company
    $author_join->field = 'entity_id';
    $author_join->left_table = 'node';
    $author_join->left_field = 'uid';
    $author_join->type = 'left';
    $view->query->add_relationship('author_company', $author_join, 'node');

    $current_join = new views_join();
    $current_join->table = 'field_data_field_company'; // 'field_company' is machine name of the user's field referencing to Company
    $current_join->field = 'field_company_target_id';
    $current_join->left_table = 'author_company';
    $current_join->left_field = 'field_company_target_id';
    $current_join->type = 'left';
    $view->query->add_relationship('current_company', $current_join, 'author_company');

    global $user;
    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
      'field' => 'current_company.entity_id',
      'value' => $user->uid,
      'operator' => '='
    );
  }
}`

Comment: What is the entity type of "Company"? Is it `Taxonomy`?

Comment: No it's a content type (node)

Comment: So a User entity has a Company node reference(s) and you want a view where other users can see Articles created by users with the same Company reference as themself?

Comment: Yes, I want a view where users can see articles created by other users with same company reference. Sorry my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want seems a bit difficult to do by simply setting the view. You might need some custom code to alter the view query. Below is an approach using [hook_views_query_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x):

1. Create a custom module (suppose it is **your_module**)
2. In file **your_module.module**, implement `hook_views_query_alter()`:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function your_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'article' && $view->current_display == 'page') { // replace 'article' and 'page' by your view's machine name and display's machine name
    $author_join = new views_join();
    $author_join->table = 'field_data_field_company'; // 'field_company' is machine name of the user's field referencing to Company
    $author_join->field = 'entity_id';
    $author_join->left_table = 'node';
    $author_join->left_field = 'uid';
    $author_join->type = 'left';
    $view->query->add_relationship('author_company', $author_join, 'node');

    $current_join = new views_join();
    $current_join->table = 'field_data_field_company'; // 'field_company' is machine name of the user's field referencing to Company
    $current_join->field = 'field_company_nid';
    $current_join->left_table = 'author_company';
    $current_join->left_field = 'field_company_nid';
    $current_join->type = 'left';
    $view->query->add_relationship('current_company', $current_join, 'author_company');

    global $user;
    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
      'field' => 'current_company.entity_id',
      'value' => $user->uid,
      'operator' => '='
    );
  }
}
```

3. Enable the module you just created.

Comment: Awesome, I already have a custom module for a few other fixes across the site so I'll try implementing this today. Is there any configurations I should set within the view? I'm honestly surprised it's not possible out of the box with Views.

Comment: With my above code, you don't need any extra configurations (relationship, filter,...) in the view. Actually, I'm not 100% sure about the what you want is impossible out of the box with Views. But I tried it with no success because it was necessary to use a combination of relationships (reference fields: Content > Author > Company > Current user) and a contextual filter (current user) while the Views didn't seem to provide enough configuration options for that.

Comment: I'm testing now with your code and you made a few mistakes. $current_join->field should be 'entity_id', correct? also, $current_join->left_field should be "entity_id" as well?

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix your code and get it working. Should be $curent_join->field = 'field-Company_reference_target_id'; and $current_join->left_field = 'field_company_reference_target_id'

Comment: Maybe my Drupal version or Reference module version differs from yours so the tables structure are different. I'm using Drupal 7.78 and Reference 7.x-2.2 for reference fields

Comment: I'm on 7.78, but 7.x-1.5 for Entity Reference. Anyways, wasn't too hard to figure out. I appreciate your help!